# Block selection in xterm

Tags: shell, console, xterm

Is it possible to have a block (as in "rectangular") selection in xterm?

If yes, is it assigned by default to a key/mouse binding or does it have to be assigned separately?

Thanks :)
Sorin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not available in `xterm`.

You can use a terminal text editor such as Vim to make selections. First you have to save your text in a file, then edit it with a text editor. In Vim, press Control+V, then use Up and Down arrow keys.

Comment: Right, I for one am looking for xterm-native block select ability for IRC and themsuch. Doesn't seem to exist as of xterm-269.

Comment: This is not about vim, it's about xterm. What if you want to copy the output of a shell command or a mysql session ?

Comment: Mysql has a batch mode, feed that output into vim -, then make the edit there. Or use vim from the mysql input prompt. More info on using vim and mysql here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9506/vi-in-mysql-for-command-editing

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's any such support in xterm, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

xterm does not have block select

Some other common terminal applications do. For example: rxvt uses the Alt key. xfce4-terminal and gnome-terminal both do block select with the control key.

Some windows terminal apps use Alt as the key modifier. Examples MobaXterm and Putty.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using an xterm through putty - I find that block selection is possible . Just hold down ALT key while making your selection with mouse - it will select a rectangular portion as u wanted !

Comment: No, you're using PuTTY and TERM=xterm (default).  That's a PuTTY feature.